# How to put a border in an EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

anybody could tell me, how to put a border in an editText in AndroidStudio?

for example a square in an editText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just try this one,

first create one XML file, inside drawable folder (use new drawable xml) and add this lines

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"/>      
<solid android:color="#000000"/>
<stroke
    android:color="#ffffff"
    android:width="05dp"/>
<corners android:radius="20dp"/>
```

then add this line inside Your edittext property

```
android:background="@drawable/(file_name)"
```

i don't know what your expecting, maybe it will help you

Answer (score 5):

It's so easy bro

First step create an **shape.xml in your directory drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<stroke 
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@android:color/black"/>
</shape>
```

Second step create your **editext in your layout.xml** and put background with the shape that you created above

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"/>
```

It's all